# D/skia(1252): --- SkImageDecoder::Factory returned null error

Tags: android

I use the following code to download an image from the Internet and show it in an Android `ImageView`.

```
private class DownloadImage extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {

    @Override
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... arg) {
        Bitmap bmp = null;
        try {
            URL url = new URL(arg[0]);
            bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(url.openConnection()
                    .getInputStream());

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return bmp;

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
        adImg.setImageBitmap(result);
        super.onPostExecute(result);
    }
}
```

However, the code results in a `D/skia(1252): --- SkImageDecoder::Factory returned null` error.

What might be the problem?

Comment: your image is not properly decoded.make sure your image is available into url path

Comment: The url sure is correct and the image is available at the path.

Comment: Check your image extension. May be the image exension is **.png** and you are trying to Compress it with **.jpeg**

Comment: then you must check (bitmap!=null) then set to your imageview.

Comment: Sorry. It works now. The problem is probably caused by a malformed url caused by json encoding. Thanks for your advice.

Comment: @SandahAung so the problem is bcoz of url being not correct

Comment: Correct. It's about the malformed URL. BTW, do I have to readjust the image view's height or is this automatically done?

Answer (score 0):

There are my reasons why this happens .
main issue ,that i found are :

- URL - might need extra permissions to access the image.
- URL- It needs HTTP get method to access the image
- The image is to large